# Prism for Windows Runtime Quick Start Code Samples failed the Windows App Certification Kit 3.1 Test

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, prism

I am planning to use the Prism for Windows Runtime in my Windows 8.1 Store App. Run the Windows App Certification Kei 3.1 over Prism for Windows Runtime, "EventAggregatorQuickStart".  The test failed at following:

Failed at Crashes and Hangs
◦Executable D:\Code Samples\WindowStoreApp81\Prism for Windows Runtime QuickStart\EventAggregatorQuickstart\EventAggregatorQuickstart\bin\Debug\AppX\EventAggregatorQuickstart.exe was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.
◦Application eventaggregatorqs_1.1.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.
◦Crash dump file C:\Users\Silong\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit\EventAggregatorQuickstart.exe.3896.dmp was created by Windows Error Reporting and provides additional information.

Failed at Performance Suspended
◦Application Error: Application Launch was not detected for application App. This could be because your application failed to launch correctly. Please consider re-running the test and avoid interacting with the application while tests are running.

Any comment on this matter is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question posted in the **Q&A** of **Windows Store Apps MSDN** site. I wonder if you posted it:

- [EventAggregatorQuickStart failed the Windows App Certification Kit 3.1 Test](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Prism-for-the-Windows-86b8fb72/view/Discussions#content)

A **QuickStart** solution is intended to show how a particular service or pattern work in a simple and intuitive way. Therefore, some other requirements that may be needed for a complete certified **Store App** might be excluded from the solution as that would not be the **QuickStart** purpose.

Anyway, you may consider running the certification tests on the **AdventuresWorkShopper RI** solution, which implements **EventAggregation** service among others, and it may be considered as a complete **Windows Store App**. This solution passes the certification tests.

**Note:** I was able to run all certification tests with **Windows App Certification Kit 3.1** over the **EventAggregator QuickStart** and ***"Performance"*** and ***"Crashes and hangs"*** tests **PASSED** successfully. I would recommend you to re-run the test avoiding application and system interaction as much as possible.

I hope this helped, regards.

Comment: Yes, I have posted there as well.  Thanks for the replay.  As mentioned over there I have found the cause of the problem.